# which collection type to use in .NET 4.5?

Tags: .net, vb.net, collections

I have been using VB.net (very old versions) for quite a while but not in the last 7-8 years. I have VS 2012 and .net 4.5 and it is clear that they have added a dizzying array (no pun intended) of collections. I have read and read on the net but am really more confused than before.

I would like some recommendations on what type of collection to use.

I have CAD entities that have:
a handle (a hexadecimal text string up to 16 characters)
a start point (a custom object with an X,Y and Z coordinate)
(optional) an end point (a custom object with an X,Y and Z coordinate)

For my purposes here I want to be able to retrieve (and delete) all entities that share a certain handle OR a certain start or end point:

```
if handle = 345 OR
if point = start point OR
if point = end point
```

I expect to have up to a couple thousand entities and will be "chaining" them. What I mean by chaining is to assemble then in a "chain" end to end. I will end up with one to many fragments of entities that form a chain.

I have a logic worked out that passes the collection of entities one time only and results in a chained result. It depend upon doing the finding using the criteria above.

Edit...extremely simplified actual data might look like this:

```
Handle: 110
Start point x: 23.17
Start point y: 18.29
End point x: 32.5
End point y: 30.72

Handle: 111
Start point x: 40.12
Start point y: 18.32

Handle: 112
Start point x: 40.12
Start point y: 40.12
End point x: 100.1
End point y: 83.2

Handle: 113
Start point x: 40.12
Start point y: 18.32
End point x: 32.5
End point y: 30.72
```

These would end up chained in this order:

```
Handle: 110
Start point x: 23.17
Start point y: 18.29
End point x: 32.5
End point y: 30.72

Handle: 113
Start point x: 40.12
Start point y: 18.32
End point x: 32.5
End point y: 30.72

Handle: 111
Start point x: 40.12
Start point y: 18.32

Handle: 112
Start point x: 40.12
Start point y: 40.12
End point x: 100.1
End point y: 83.2
```

What collection would you vb.net experts recommend?

Comment: Collections are .NET and not specific to VB

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on how often you're going to be deleting entities. If you're talking just a few thousand entities and you're not going to be doing a mass delete hundreds of times per second, then a simple [LinkedList(Of Entity)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx) is really easy. That gives you your "chain".

To delete items that match your criteria (my code is in C#, but you can probably translate it easily enough):

```
chain = new LinkedList<Entity>();
// some code populates the linked list.

// now, to delete
LinkedListNode<Entity> node = chain.First;
while (node != null)
{
    LinkedListNode<Entity> nextNode = node.Next;
    if (node.Value.handle = searchHandle ||
        node.Value.startPoint.Equals(searchStartPoint) ||
        node.Value.endPoint.Equals(searchEndPoint)
    {
        // remove the node
        chain.Remove(node);
    }
    node = nextNode;
}
```

You could do this with a `List(Of Entity)`, but removal would be much slower as would be inserting an item into the middle of the chain.

Comment: A linked list is exactly what I would need to store the sorted entities in. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a dictionary with a custom key type that override `GetHashCode` where the result depends on the value of your handle or point coordinates. I'd also add a value wrapper class that acts as a linked-list that contains references to the next element in your chain.

Comment: "I'd also add a value wrapper class that acts as a linked-list that contains references to the next element in your chain." - not sure what you mean here? I was going to make a class that had two properties: previous entity and next entity. Is that what you mean?

Comment: What you describe is a linked-list, yes.

Comment: Also, thanks for the really quick reply. I look into custom key type that override GetHashCode

Comment: I don't quite see how I could make a unique key using the handle OR the first point OR the second point all in the same key. It's like I need three different keys???

Answer (score 0):

I think you could just use List(Of T).

For example:

```
List(Of MyCADEntry) listEntries = new List( Of MyCADEntry )();
```

and then use LINQ for things like

```
listEntries.Where( Function(x) x.StartPoint == point );
```